# JQGrid Master Detail select/ MultiSelect on details grid not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, jqgrid

I am trying Master Detail scenario in ASP.NET MVC 3 (default view engine) .

I was able to go through the following code  at http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html  and get master detail working. The problem is that when I select any row in details 
the first row seems to get selected / unselected
clicking on link to find selected id's return **,null,null,null,null,nul**

Have anyone of you experienced the same.

if you can point me to working ASP.NET MVC example with JQGrid Master Details , it will be much appreciated.

Regards,

Mar

**Edit - Code**

1-  View Page

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/default.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<dynamic>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Orders Available
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <link href="../../Content/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="../../Scripts/themes/redmond/jquery-ui-1.8.6.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"
        type="text/css" />
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/js/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="scriptContent" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            jQuery("#list10").jqGrid({
                url: '/order/list/',
                datatype: "json",
                mtype: 'post',
                colNames: ['PurchaseOrder', 'SalesOrder', 'OrderDate', 'Supplier', 'Status', "Details"],
                colModel: [
      { name: 'PurchaseOrder', index: 'PurchaseOrder', width: 100, align: 'left' },
                            { name: 'SalesOrder', index: 'SalesOrder', width: 100, align: 'left' },
                            { name: 'OrderDate', index: 'OrderDate', width: 75, align: 'left' },
                            { name: 'Supplier', index: 'Supplier', width: 150, align: 'left' },
                            { name: 'Status', index: 'Status', width: 50, align: 'left' },                          
                            { name: 'Details', index: 'Details', width: 50, align: 'left' }
    ],
                rowNum: 10,
                rowList: [10, 20, 30],
                pager: '#pager10',
                sortname: 'id',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: "desc",
                multiselect: false,
                caption: "Invoice Header",
                onSelectRow: function (ids) {
                    if (ids == null) {
                        ids = 0;
                        if (jQuery("#list10_d").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records') > 0) {
                            jQuery("#list10_d").jqGrid('setGridParam', { url: "/order/detail/id=" + ids, page: 1 });
                            jQuery("#list10_d").jqGrid('setCaption', "Invoice Detail: " + ids)
                .trigger('reloadGrid');
                        }
                    } else {
                        jQuery("#list10_d").jqGrid('setGridParam', { url: "/order/detail/id=" + ids, page: 1 });
                        jQuery("#list10_d").jqGrid('setCaption', "Invoice Detail: " + ids)
            .trigger('reloadGrid');
                    }
                }
            });
            jQuery("#list10").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager10', { add: false, edit: false, del: false });
            jQuery("#list10_d").jqGrid({
                height: 100,
                url: "/order/detail/",
                datatype: "json",
                colNames: ['Stock Number', 'Description', 'Available', 'Required'],
                colModel: [
        { name: 'PartNumber', index: 'StockNumber', width: 100, align: 'left' },
                            { name: 'Description', index: 'Description', width: 200, align: 'left' },
                            { name: 'Available', index: 'Available', width: 75, align: 'left' },
                            { name: 'Required', index: 'Required', width: 75, align: 'left' }
    ],
                rowNum: 5,
                rowList: [5, 10, 20],
                pager: '#pager10_d',
                sortname: 'item',
                viewrecords: true,
                sortorder: "asc",
                multiselect: true,
                caption: "Invoice Detail",
                beforeSelectRow: function(rowid, e) { return true; }

            }).navGrid('#pager10_d', { add: false, edit: false, del: false });
            jQuery("#ms1").click(function () {
                var s;
                s = jQuery("#list10_d").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
                alert(s);
            });

        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainContent" runat="server">
    <div class="orderSelSum">
        <h3>
            Summary</h3>
        <p>
            Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots
            in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.
            Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked
            up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage,
            and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the
            undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus
            Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC.
            This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance.
            The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a line
            in section 1.10.32</p>
    </div>
    <div id="orderMain">
        <table id="list10">
        </table>
        <div id="pager10">
        </div>
        <br />
        Invoice Detail
        <table id="list10_d">
        </table>
        <div id="pager10_d">
        </div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="ms1">Get Selected id's</a>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

2- JSon result

a) For Master Table

```
{"total":10,"page":1,"records":4,"rows":[{"id":"4cf2c07d-1f13-4add-8bf9-3e7bca441a69","cell":["NV32653-A","23434324","03/01/2010","MY Supplier","Ready for Use","\u003ca href=\u0027#\u0027\u003eDetails\u003c/a\u003e"]},{"id":"54f3b266-dd14-4137-ab76-6d4a1fd7fe7c","cell":["NV32653-A","23434324","03/01/2010","MY Supplier","Ready for Use","\u003ca href=\u0027#\u0027\u003eDetails\u003c/a\u003e"]},{"id":"ab63a5ae-1f00-43ed-a50e-d8fb60ff2df2","cell":["NV32653-A","23434324","03/01/2010","MY Supplier","Ready for Use","\u003ca href=\u0027#\u0027\u003eDetails\u003c/a\u003e"]},{"id":"484c0e05-80c6-4259-8a29-ca6be83037e4","cell":["NV32653-A","23434324","03/01/2010","MY Supplier","Ready for Use","\u003ca href=\u0027#\u0027\u003eDetails\u003c/a\u003e"]}]}
```

b) Details

```
{"rows":[{"id":null,"cell":["PART A","Apple ","10","0"]},{"id":null,"cell":["PART B","Orange","12","0"]},{"id":null,"cell":["PART C","Banana","8","0"]},{"id":null,"cell":["PART D","Bread","10","0"]},{"id":null,"cell":["Part E","Jam","9","0"]}]}
```

Some Images

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Update 1**
found that details json contains null for ID field. I will correct that soon.

Comment: From what I've seen, people are much more inclined to offer assistance to people who appreciate and accept their answers.

Comment: @PolishedTurd- I understand what you are saying, some of my questions do not really have any answer and some I have answered myself and I am/was not sure if I should select my answer as answer.

Comment: Yeah, if your own is the appropriate answer, definitely mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem which you have to take in consideration in Master/Detail scenario is the choose of ids in both tables. It is important to understand, that jqGrid use the id returned from the server as ids of `<tr>` elements of the grid. So if you use for both table the same ids (duplicates) you will have conflicts.

It you do still have problem with the implementation of Master/Detail scenario you should append your question with the code example and some test data. One can save the test JSON data to a text files to simulate the server responses so no server code is required.

Comment: @Oleg- thank you for replying. I will append the code shortly after creating non proprietary data for display.

Comment: @Oleg- I have updated post with additional details. because you talked about Ids, I am thinking, could it be possible thatall ids currently being null are being treated as same and causing this issue.

Comment: @Oleg - You were right about Ids. Thank you. All Id's being null caused the issue.

Comment: @TheMar: OK I see. Fine! I will examine it tomorrow and write you more.

Comment: @TheMar: Good to here it! You can just use a string as id and use one prefix for the first grig and another for the second. But the value "id":null looks more as a bug on the server side. If should be easy to look in the server code (debug it) to find the error.

Comment: @oleg- Yes it was a server side bug. Guid was not getting initialized in Mock up repository.

Comment: @Oleg- the issue I was facing is gone. I can get the master detail working fine. I am working on cell editing inside details now. Thanks