# JQGrid afterCellEdit function

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

After working on with [master detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118936/jqgrid-master-detail-select-multiselect-on-details-grid-not-working) with JQGrid , I am  trying to get partial view data added to a div block.

what I am trying to do is

afterEditCell: function () {

```
                $.ajax(
                    url: "/order/Selected/",
                    type: "GET",
                    success: function (response, status, xhr) {
                        var jqContainer = $('.right');
                        jqContainer.html(response);
```

)
                        },

I am using inline cell editing

jQuery('#list10_d').jqGrid('editRow', id, true,);

ONce I edit value in cell  it does send the update to server  wher I am able to update selected dataitems with value.

Once this is done I want to load partial view which contains information about selected data item

afterEditCell  event never fires.

I have checked the ajax call by adding it to $().ready.

Am I using the right event.  Is there a better way to add partial view after row has been edited?

Regards,

Mar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a misunderstanding because jqGrid is a grid which can do probably too many things. The problem is that [Inline Editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing), [Form Editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing) and [Cell Editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing) are three absolutely different implementation of jgGrid editing. You can combine [Inline Editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing) and [Form Editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aform_editing). There are some [common grid settings](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules) used during all of editing modes. The events used by [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#editrow) can be defined as parameters of [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#editrow). You can use `succesfunc` or `aftersavefunc` for your purpose. [The Events of the cell editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#events) will be
not fired by [editRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#editrow) which is the part of [Inline Editing](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing).

Comment: Oleg- thanks again for coming to rescue. I have been reading about JQGrid and now understand what you are saying about different implementation of editing. Is there any resource (other than documentation) where JQGrid has been explained in detail

Answer (score 0):

I may have got one solution from another post on SO

[jqgrid reload grid after successfull inline update / inline creation of record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2109754/jqgrid-reload-grid-after-successfull-inline-update-inline-creation-of-record)

added

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {




            function updateSelected(rowid, result) {
                alert("Hello");
                return true;
            }
```

and inside JQGrid script

```
jqGrid('editRow', id, true, '', updateSelected, '', '', '');
```

Though it works for me I will stillwant to know if it is possible to do so using cell events?

Regards,

Mar